# Passing data to partial view ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my top menu bar with a list of actionlink(). One of them will pass data to controller.

```
int? partCategoryID = Model.SelectedPartCategory == null ? -1 : Model.SelectedPartCategory.PartCategoryID;
@Html.ActionLink("New Part", "NewPart", new { PartCategoryID = partCategoryID })
```

It is working fine. Then I found the number of actionlinks is growing too fast. So I'm trying to build a site map. and the view will pass all actionlink data to a partial view. And the partial handles all top menu bars.

In the original view (simplified):

```
Dictionary<string, object> actionRouteValueDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
int? partCategoryID = Model.SelectedPartCategory == null ? -1 : Model.SelectedPartCategory.PartCategoryID;
actionRouteValueDict.Add("NewPart", new { PartCategoryID = partCategoryID });
@Html.Partial("TopNavBar", new ViewDataDictionary { {"Routes", actionRouteValueDict} });
```

In the partial view, it's "doing the same thing":

```
Dictionary<string, object> actionRouteValueDict = (Dictionary<string, object>)ViewData["Routes"];
@Html.ActionLink("New Part", "NewPart", actionRouteValueDict["NewPart"])
```

But somehow, the new `@Html.Action` cannot process the object correctly, I can debug and see the `actionRouteValueDict["NewPart"]` is still correct `({PartCategory = -1})`, but `ActionLink` translated to `Length=4`. 
I know I can pass something safer than object, like the html string. But I want to know what I did wrong over here. And how to fix by passing object through views.

Comment: Why are you not just passing the model to the partial?

Comment: This partial view is to display the site map, it can get the model data by query database. In normal case, it can generate all pages. In general, the only data need to pass to the partial view is what's my current page, so it will be displayed in a different color. But in some special situation, the link in the site map need the route object (depends on the current view). That's what my question is about. When passing the route object to partial view. The ActionLink() in the partial cannot display it correctly. The rest of the data are not useful for this partial view.

Comment: Why? If you were already doing it in with code in the main view based on the model, just use `@Html.Partial("TopNavBar", Model)` to pass the model to the partial and then move the code you were previously using to the partial. but in any case, you really should be using `@Html.Action()` to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns a partial of your menu.

Answer (score 1):

Chris,Generally this translation to Length=4 problem will occur, when we forget to set null for the Html attribute

I hope you are using the below overload of ActionLink:

[image]

If so, try to set null for final parameter,  that is **IDictionary htmlAttribute to null** and see that works or not.

**So you code will look like:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Part", "NewPart", actionRouteValueDict["NewPart"], null)
```

Hope this will help to solve your problem, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
Karthik